# Python - Replacing characters in a list

Tags: python, list

I'm working on a Python script which opens a DBF file, and then from that creates a text output of the contents (either .txt or .csv).

I've now managed to get it writing the output file, but I need to replace the space character in one of the database fields (It's a UK Car registration number, e.g. I need "AB09 CDE" to output as "AB09CDE") but I've been unable to work out how to do this as it seems to be nested lists. The field is rec[7] in the code below.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
 import sys, csv
 from cStringIO import StringIO
 from operator import itemgetter

 # Read a database
 filename = 'DATABASE.DBF'
 if len(sys.argv) == 2:
     filename = sys.argv[1]
 f = open(filename, 'rb')
 db = list(dbfreader(f))
 f.close()
 fieldnames, fieldspecs, records = db[0], db[1], db[2:]

 # Remove some fields that we don't want to use...
 del fieldnames[0:]
 del fieldspecs[0:]
 #Put the relevant data into the temporary table
 records = [rec[7:8] + rec[9:12] + rec[3:4] for rec in records]


 # Create outputfile
 output_file = 'OUTPUT.txt'
 f = open (output_file, 'wb')
 csv.writer(f).writerows(records)
```

This also adds a lot of spaces to the end of each outputted value. How would I get rid of these?

I'm fairly new to Python so any guidance would be gratefully received!

Comment: Please give an example of the nested list.

Comment: I am confused by your nested list statement.  Spaces can be replaced in a list of strings using `[i.replace(' ', '') for i in my_list]`.  You can remove leading and trailing whitespace using `[i.strip() for i in my_list]`.

Comment: What do you mean by an example of the nested list? Do you mean the data that's contained within the DBF file?

Comment: dont try to stick with list comprehension, if you need to operate on a single item in a more complex way. `rec[7:8].replace(' ', '')` could do the trick, but maybe you require some more operations on that `rec[7:8]` --> expand the for loop

Comment: I mean the variable `db` you get. @KrisReynolds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using slicing:

```
>>> L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> L[7]
8
>>> L[7:8]  #NOTE: it's a *list* of a single element!
[8]
```

To replace spaces in `rec[7]` do:

```
records = [[rec[7].replace(' ', '')] + rec[9:12] + rec[3:4] for rec in records]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 records = [rec[7].replace(' ', '') + rec[9:12] + rec[3:4] for rec in records]
```

?

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: Sorry - I had accidentally made another edit and saved it! This worked - thank you

Answer (score 1):

Python documentation wrote: 
str.replace(old, new[, count]) Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.
This example demonstrate it:

```
In [13]: a ="AB09CDE"

In [14]: a.replace(" ", "")
Out[14]: 'AB09CDE'

In [15]: print a
AB09CDE
```

So, if rec is string field, then:

```
records = [rec.replace(" ", "") for rec in records]
```